# Shared properties of several extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ring-theory, extension-field

Some answers may be obvious but for the sake of symmetry let me please ask my question in this general form:

Consider the pairs of rings

1. $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{3}]$
2. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$
3. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$

Note that

- $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}] = \{a_0 + \frac{a_1}{2} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{2^n}  \ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}, a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$
- $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] = \{a_0 + a_1\sqrt{2} + \dots + a_n\sqrt{2}^n  \ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}, a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{a_0 + a_1\sqrt{2}  \ |\ a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

My question is:

> Which [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_ring_theory#Types_of_rings) [properties](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/) do the members of each
>   pair have in common and which ones not?

For $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{3}]$ I cannot see which ring properties they could **not** have in common.

For $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ I believe to know that there **are** such properties, due to the fact, that both square roots of $2$ are real while only one cubic root of $2$ is real.

For $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ I am not sure. I suspect they may have different properties, since Franz Lemmermeyer in his book [Quadratische Zahlkörper](https://books.google.de/books/about/Quadratische_Zahlk%C3%B6rper.html?id=z5ErDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (unfortunately only in German) discusses in detail the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ but not $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ (which would have been the more natural example when both were essentially the same).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ are all Dedekind domains. They are even all Euclidean domains and so PIDs.

$\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{3}]$ are PIDs. So is every subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is not a Dedekind domain because it is not integrally closed. In fact, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ with $d$ squarefree is a Dedekind domain iff $d \equiv 2,3 \bmod 4$.

Comment: For what it's worth, ${\mathbb Z}[\frac12]$ and ${\mathbb Z}[\frac13]$ are Dedekind and Euclidean rings as well.